# checking if a list element exists in R with exists() function

Tags: r

i need to check if an list element exists in R and if not, i need to create one. This happens inside a function.

I have a named list (currently with empty lists):

```
> comparisonLog
$`01-response.json`
NULL

$`02-response.json`
NULL

$`03-response.json`
NULL

$`04-response.json`
NULL

$`05-response.json`
NULL
```

i am interested in the third element:

```
elementOfInterest <- responseIterator[[3]]
> elementOfInterest
[3] "03-response.json"
```

Why am i getting en error here?

```
exists("price", where = comparisonLog[[elementOfInterest]])
Error in as.environment(where) : using 'as.environment(NULL)' is defunct
```

Comment: I'm not still not sure what you want to do. Can you show an example where your test would be TRUE? (i.e., if the third element of `comparisonLog` contains an element called `price`?) Are you looking for `"price" %in% names(comparisonLog[[responseIterator]])` ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use `comparisonLog[[responseIterator]]` for the argument `where`, rather than `comparisonLog[[responseIterator]][[]]`

```
> exists("price", where = comparisonLog[[3]])
[1] TRUE
```

**Dummy Data**

```
> dput(comparisonLog)
list(A = list(price = 1), B = list(price = 1), C = list(price = 1), 
    D = list(price = 1), E = list(price = 1))
```

Comment: maybe i wasnt clear, "price" would be an subelement: comparisonLog[[responseIterator]][["price"]]

Comment: @Nneka I am not sure if I caught your point right. See my update.